# Best way to apply shadow to each side of wrapper

Tags: css, border, shadow

I guess this is a very typical design, there is a full screen background image, and a centred wrapper for the content with a white background. The left and right edge of this white wrapper there is a neat shadow a few pixels wide. Similar to [this site](http://www.santandersalt.co.uk/).

What is the best way to achieve this? Background image (and if so, on what and how?) or border, something else? Any help appreciated.

Edit: I need this to be supported on IE7.

Comment: google box-shadow u will get ur answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For support back to IE7 I'd recommend using an image. Your image would be placed on the body tag aligned top / center and repeated on the Y-Axis. The image itself would be one pixel in height and as wide as it needs to be for your design. Anyone who is competent with photoshop could create this for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I was considering, but it's a shame it makes life difficult if the site is responsive as the background image would have to be fixed width. Oh well, I may try and use CSS3 with a filter/hack for IE instead. Wish IE would die already!

Comment: Cool. It wouldn't really be as much of an issue for when the site is viewed on smaller devices such as a mobile screen. You could simply hide the BG image via the media query. The drop shadow works well on larger screen which have decent width (white space) to each side of the site but on a smaller screen where there would be virtually no width (white space) either side I think it would probably be okay not to have it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS3 `box-shadow` property.

```
#wrapper {
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

All modern browsers support this feature, but if you need to support IE < 9, you'll need to use images or external libraries such as [PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

More info about browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: Will this be supported back to IE7 and FF3.0?

Comment: Nope. FF supports it since 3.5 (with `-moz-` prefix)

Comment: who use ie7 nowadays? really incredible